# Upload csv is not uploaded to the server after generate

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have this code :

```
$file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'w+');

fputcsv($file, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));

$data = array(
   array('Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'),
   array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'),
   array('Data 31', 'Data 32', 'Data 33', 'Data 34', 'Data 35'),
   array('Data 1', 'Data 42', 'Data 43', 'Data 44', 'Data 45'),
   array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55')
            );

   foreach ($data as $row)
   {
       fputcsv($file, $row);
   }

   fclose($file);
   move_uploaded_file($file, $campaignFolder.'/'.'test.csv');
```

My campaign folder is the full path to the folder, I tested and this directory has 777, but the folder is added in the root of project with the name `demosaved.csv`. I don't understand where the problem is. Please help me. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the content of `$campainFolder` ? (by content, I mean the result of `var_dump($campaignFolder);`)

Comment: @Cid : `/home/ciotu/Public/Projects/project/symfony/src/../public/report/9/2018/08`

Comment: `move_uploaded_file`? What's the purpose of using this function?

Comment: Move the .csv file after generation of him

Comment: Why do you move file? Why can't you write to the file at the exact location?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). The first parameter should be the location of the file, the second should be the destination.

Comment: @u_mulder how is possible to do that ? can you explain please in few words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file` **moves the file that was uploaded**. Your `demosaved.csv` file is not uploaded by anyone, so `move_uploaded_file` is totally **useless**. You code should be something like:

```
// create the file at path where you need it
$file = fopen($campaignFolder.'/'.'test.csv', 'w+');

fputcsv($file, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));

$data = array(
   array('Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'),
   array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'),
   array('Data 31', 'Data 32', 'Data 33', 'Data 34', 'Data 35'),
   array('Data 1', 'Data 42', 'Data 43', 'Data 44', 'Data 45'),
   array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55')
);

foreach ($data as $row) {
   fputcsv($file, $row);
}

fclose($file);
```